# Shallow nested Rails routing with :as

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want:

- Every projectpart to belong to a
  project.
- Every solution to belong to a
  projectart (and to a project through
  that projectpart).
- Every image to belong to a solution
  (and to a project and a projectpart
  through that solution.)
- Every document to belong to a
  solution (and to a project and a
  projectpart through that solution.)
- Every URL to be as short as simple as
  possible.
- Every case of "projectpart" to appear
  as "part" in every URL. (I couldn't
  call the model "part" on Heroku.)

Can anyone tell me why this...

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :projects, :shallow => true do |project|
    project.resources :projectparts do |part|
      part.resources :solutions do |solution|
        solution.resources :images
        solution.resources :documents
      end
    end
  end
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

...is leaving a whole bunch of cases of "projectpart" in my URLs...

```
steven-nobles-imac-200:drominay steven$ rake routes
(in /Users/steven/Drominay)

                          projects GET    /projects                                           {:controller=>"projects", :action=>"index"}
                formatted_projects GET    /projects.:format                                   {:controller=>"projects", :action=>"index"}
                                   POST   /projects                                           {:controller=>"projects", :action=>"create"}
                                   POST   /projects.:format                                   {:controller=>"projects", :action=>"create"}
                       new_project GET    /projects/new                                       {:controller=>"projects", :action=>"new"}
             formatted_new_project GET    /projects/new.:format                               {:controller=>"projects", :action=>"new"}
                      edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit                                  {:controller=>"projects", :action=>"edit"}
            formatted_edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit.:format                          {:controller=>"projects", :action=>"edit"}
                           project GET    /projects/:id                                       {:controller=>"projects", :action=>"show"}
                 formatted_project GET    /projects/:id.:format                               {:controller=>"projects", :action=>"show"}
                                   PUT    /projects/:id                                       {:controller=>"projects", :action=>"update"}
                                   PUT    /projects/:id.:format                               {:controller=>"projects", :action=>"update"}
                                   DELETE /projects/:id                                       {:controller=>"projects", :action=>"destroy"}
                                   DELETE /projects/:id.:format                               {:controller=>"projects", :action=>"destroy"}
              project_projectparts GET    /projects/:project_id/projectparts                  {:controller=>"projectparts", :action=>"index"}
    formatted_project_projectparts GET    /projects/:project_id/projectparts.:format          {:controller=>"projectparts", :action=>"index"}
                                   POST   /projects/:project_id/projectparts                  {:controller=>"projectparts", :action=>"create"}
                                   POST   /projects/:project_id/projectparts.:format          {:controller=>"projectparts", :action=>"create"}
           new_project_projectpart GET    /projects/:project_id/projectparts/new              {:controller=>"projectparts", :action=>"new"}
 formatted_new_project_projectpart GET    /projects/:project_id/projectparts/new.:format      {:controller=>"projectparts", :action=>"new"}
                  edit_projectpart GET    /projectparts/:id/edit                              {:controller=>"projectparts", :action=>"edit"}
        formatted_edit_projectpart GET    /projectparts/:id/edit.:format                      {:controller=>"projectparts", :action=>"edit"}
                       projectpart GET    /projectparts/:id                                   {:controller=>"projectparts", :action=>"show"}
             formatted_projectpart GET    /projectparts/:id.:format                           {:controller=>"projectparts", :action=>"show"}
                                   PUT    /projectparts/:id                                   {:controller=>"projectparts", :action=>"update"}
                                   PUT    /projectparts/:id.:format                           {:controller=>"projectparts", :action=>"update"}
                                   DELETE /projectparts/:id                                   {:controller=>"projectparts", :action=>"destroy"}
                                   DELETE /projectparts/:id.:format                           {:controller=>"projectparts", :action=>"destroy"}
             projectpart_solutions GET    /projectparts/:projectpart_id/solutions             {:controller=>"solutions", :action=>"index"}
   formatted_projectpart_solutions GET    /projectparts/:projectpart_id/solutions.:format     {:controller=>"solutions", :action=>"index"}
                                   POST   /projectparts/:projectpart_id/solutions             {:controller=>"solutions", :action=>"create"}
                                   POST   /projectparts/:projectpart_id/solutions.:format     {:controller=>"solutions", :action=>"create"}
          new_projectpart_solution GET    /projectparts/:projectpart_id/solutions/new         {:controller=>"solutions", :action=>"new"}
formatted_new_projectpart_solution GET    /projectparts/:projectpart_id/solutions/new.:format {:controller=>"solutions", :action=>"new"}
                     edit_solution GET    /solutions/:id/edit                                 {:controller=>"solutions", :action=>"edit"}
           formatted_edit_solution GET    /solutions/:id/edit.:format                         {:controller=>"solutions", :action=>"edit"}
                          solution GET    /solutions/:id                                      {:controller=>"solutions", :action=>"show"}
                formatted_solution GET    /solutions/:id.:format                              {:controller=>"solutions", :action=>"show"}
                                   PUT    /solutions/:id                                      {:controller=>"solutions", :action=>"update"}
                                   PUT    /solutions/:id.:format                              {:controller=>"solutions", :action=>"update"}
                                   DELETE /solutions/:id                                      {:controller=>"solutions", :action=>"destroy"}
                                   DELETE /solutions/:id.:format                              {:controller=>"solutions", :action=>"destroy"}
                   solution_images GET    /solutions/:solution_id/images                      {:controller=>"images", :action=>"index"}
         formatted_solution_images GET    /solutions/:solution_id/images.:format              {:controller=>"images", :action=>"index"}
                                   POST   /solutions/:solution_id/images                      {:controller=>"images", :action=>"create"}
                                   POST   /solutions/:solution_id/images.:format              {:controller=>"images", :action=>"create"}
                new_solution_image GET    /solutions/:solution_id/images/new                  {:controller=>"images", :action=>"new"}
      formatted_new_solution_image GET    /solutions/:solution_id/images/new.:format          {:controller=>"images", :action=>"new"}
                        edit_image GET    /images/:id/edit                                    {:controller=>"images", :action=>"edit"}
              formatted_edit_image GET    /images/:id/edit.:format                            {:controller=>"images", :action=>"edit"}
                             image GET    /images/:id                                         {:controller=>"images", :action=>"show"}
                   formatted_image GET    /images/:id.:format                                 {:controller=>"images", :action=>"show"}
                                   PUT    /images/:id                                         {:controller=>"images", :action=>"update"}
                                   PUT    /images/:id.:format                                 {:controller=>"images", :action=>"update"}
                                   DELETE /images/:id                                         {:controller=>"images", :action=>"destroy"}
                                   DELETE /images/:id.:format                                 {:controller=>"images", :action=>"destroy"}
                solution_documents GET    /solutions/:solution_id/documents                   {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"index"}
      formatted_solution_documents GET    /solutions/:solution_id/documents.:format           {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"index"}
                                   POST   /solutions/:solution_id/documents                   {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"create"}
                                   POST   /solutions/:solution_id/documents.:format           {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"create"}
             new_solution_document GET    /solutions/:solution_id/documents/new               {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"new"}
   formatted_new_solution_document GET    /solutions/:solution_id/documents/new.:format       {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"new"}
                     edit_document GET    /documents/:id/edit                                 {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"edit"}
           formatted_edit_document GET    /documents/:id/edit.:format                         {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"edit"}
                          document GET    /documents/:id                                      {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"show"}
                formatted_document GET    /documents/:id.:format                              {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"show"}
                                   PUT    /documents/:id                                      {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"update"}
                                   PUT    /documents/:id.:format                              {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"update"}
                                   DELETE /documents/:id                                      {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"destroy"}
                                   DELETE /documents/:id.:format                              {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"destroy"}
                                          /:controller/:action/:id                            
                                          /:controller/:action/:id.:format
```

...and yet is not generating basic URL helpers, like this?

```
undefined method `project_projectpart_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x3438ffc> (ActionView::TemplateError)
```

BTW, everything except changing "projectpart" to "part" in every URL was working fine with this more verbose syntax:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|


  map.resources :projects, :has_many => :projectparts
  map.resources :projects, :has_many => :solutions
  map.resources :projects, :has_many => :images
  map.resources :projects, :has_many => :documents
  map.resources :projectparts, :has_many => :solutions
  map.resources :projectparts, :has_many => :images
  map.resources :projectparts, :has_many => :documents
  map.resources :solutions, :has_many => :images
  map.resources :solutions, :has_many => :documents
  map.resources :images
  map.resources :documents


  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'

end
```

Comment: Can you simplify that question a bit? Remove the routes that have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Done. Originally I didn't want to make any assumptions about what might be relevant to the question. But now that it's answered, I can safely edit out the unrelated code which I've done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question about route generation is `:shallow => true`

Providing the shallow option will create longer routes for collection methods of the inner resource(s), while providing shallow routes for member methods of those nested resource(s). Take a closer look at the routes created and you'll see this.

Essentially routes that need an id (edit,update,show,destroy) will the short one containing only the inner most resource . Routes that don't need an id(index,new) will be slightly longer, containing the immediate parent.

You don't need `project_projectpart_path` because the project in `project_projectpart` can be implied from the project part. Instead just use `projectpart_path` for existing project parts.

Your second example provides those missing routes because it never gives the shallow option.

Changing 'projectpart' to 'part' in urls is as simple as adding the :as option in it's definition. Sorry it won't work with the shorthand :has_many version

```
map.resources :projects, :shallow => true do |project|
  project.resources :projectparts, :as => "part" do |part|
    part.resources :solutions do |solution|
      solution.resources :images
      solution.resources :documents
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi EmFi. Fabulous, thanks. I forgot to mention, I wanted each projectpart's ID to be unique within each project, so that every project will have a projectpart with an ID of 1, but none hopefully will have a projectpart with an ID of 132513452345. I've taken your format, removed the :shallow, and split it into two nestings, one from @projects to @solutions inclusive, and the other from @solutions to @images/@documents inclusive. Much appreciated.

Comment: Making context sensitive ID's is not built into Rails. I've never used it, but the composite primary keys plugin (http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/) should be able to help you out here.

Comment: Cheers. I was going to add a partcount column to the projectparts table and call it via friendly_id, but this looks like a handy alternative.